# Realistic water in blender, what bake resolution should I use

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to make some realistic water in blender. I'm just wondering what the optimal resolution to use would be during baking. Would 500 suffice? Thanks!

Comment: it depends on the scale of the simulation and a few other things, usually you have to try by trial and error per scene

Comment: 500 is **very** high res from my tests...like NoviceInDisguise said, it is sort of trial and error. Remember that Blender's fluid simulator is for small scale fluids: cup of water, fish tank, bathtub (maybe); not for things like oceans, swimming pools, lakes, etc..

Comment: Ok, I'll mess around with it a bit, I've got no problem with trial and error. I just wasn't sure if there was some threshold between "realistic" and "non-realistic".

Comment: The question is impossible to answer, but in my experience, 500 is not very much. Sure, it may work for small scale stuff, but usually I tend to use something like 650 or more for the final product. It all depends on the scene and the domain size, however.